# Install VNC on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition in my laptop. I need to install vnc on it. I have downloaded [VNC for Linux Debian-compatible installer 64-bit](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/). I have no idea about how to install it because I'm new to Linux environment. I have google and find lot of tutorials about how to install vnc on Ubuntu 14.04 Server edition. But unable to find how to install vnc downloaded from [realvnc](https://www.realvnc.com) site on Ubuntu Desktop edition.

I need a help to install RealVNC on my Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with a VNC client pre-installed, so you don't actually have to download or install anything. It's called Remmina and is pretty awesome. At least, I haven't had any problems with it. I can control all the PC's on my LAN including the Windows machines as well as tunnel a VNC session through SSH in order to securely connect to my work computer over the internet.

Ubuntu also has a VNC server pre-installed. To set it up just search for "desktop sharing".

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help.